# Troubleshooting Microsoft Entra ID ACS Redirection Issue in Spring Boot Application Running on VM

Tags: azure-active-directory, virtual-machine, acs, idp, microsoft-entra-id

I'm encountering an issue with a Spring Boot application that connects to an Identity Provider (IDP) such as Azure Active Directory. The IDP's redirection URL (ACS) is configured as http://localhost:8080. However, when the application runs on a VM, this URL changes to http://10.1.4.125:8080. The IDP does not recognize this address and only accepts URIs with HTTPS or HTTP but with localhost. How can I address this issue?

Comment: The questions you answer tend to be about MS Azure configuration, pricing, infrastructure, and other cloud-related issues, instead of being practical programming problems. StackOverflow is meant to discuss only programming questions. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
for more details. Please post your non-programming question on other platforms such as [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/)
, and [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/tags/133/azure)
for immediate help. Thanks!